# Swift: Removing only one MKPolyline of several

Tags: swift, mapkit, overlay, mkpolyline

I have two polylines on the map:

```
var polylineRoute : MKGeodesicPolyline!  
var polylineFlight : MKGeodesicPolyline!
```

I assign each of them a title and add them to the map like this (in different methods):

```
let polyline = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: &routeCoordinates, count: routeCoordinates.count)  
polyline.title = "route"  
self.mapView.addOverlay(polyline)  
self.polylineRoute = polyline
```

and

```
let polyline = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: &routeCoordinates, count: routeCoordinates.count)  
polyline.title = "flight"  
self.mapView.addOverlay(polyline)  
self.polylineFlight = polyline
```

Now, when a specific action is triggered, I would like to remove only the flight overlay and leave the route overlay intact.

This does not work at all:

```
func removeFlightPath()  
    {  
        self.mapView.removeOverlay(self.polylineFlight)  
        self.polylineFlight = nil  
    }
```

The following works but removes both polylines:

```
func removeFlightPath()  
{  
        var overlays = mapView.overlays  
        mapView.removeOverlays(overlays)  
}
```

Is there a working way to remove only one polyline? I searched the forum and there is only one response that is saying that it is possible using the title. However, it does not specify how it can be done.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

This solves the issue:

```
func removeFlightPath()
    {
        if self.polylineFlight != nil
        {
            // Overlays that must be removed from the map
            var overlaysToRemove = [MKOverlay]()

            // All overlays on the map
            let overlays = self.mapView.overlays

            for overlay in overlays
            {
                if overlay.title! == "flight"
                {
                    overlaysToRemove.append(overlay)
                }
            }

            self.mapView.removeOverlays(overlaysToRemove)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact syntax, but have you tried checking the overlays array for the polyline with the title "flight" and removing that one?

Comment: Great solution. When I create my lines I now pass in a title which contains the type I want and a number.                                                    buildingPolyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
        buildingPolyline.title = withTitle
        mapView.add(buildingPolyline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your source code is correct. Could be that the reference counting is messing it up. As long as the object is referred to, MKGeodesicPolyline will not be removed.  In your code, you have used a local variable to create the polyline object.  I have tried it without using a local variable and it is removing the polyline.

```
self.polylineFlight = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: &routeCoordinates, count: routeCoordinates.count)  
self.polylineFlight.title = "flight"
```

Comment: Thank you, Christian! I have also come up with another solution (included in the original post). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`polylineFlight` doesn't look right. It's built from `routeCoordinates`, the same as `polylineRoute`.  So removing it would produce no change in the map.

Are you building from the right coordinates?

Can we see before/after screenshots? Or can we see a clarification of "does not work at all"?

Comment: Hal. Thank you. As I said, the both polylines are created in different methods, so these are two different polylines. "Does not work at all" meant that the polyline remained on the map after the removing action had been triggered. I have figured it out (included in the EDIT paragraph of my original post). Nevertheless, thank you for support.

Comment: this is not an answer, but should be in the comment section